# Disabling a button when two text fields are empty

Tags: java, awt

Okay so I want to disable a button when both tfLastName and tfFirstname are empty. I'm currently using this code snippet but it enables the button even if the tfLastName is empty. What do I do to solve this? Any input would be appreciated.

```
public void launchFrame(){
//irrelevant code
tfLastName.addKeyListener(null);
tfFirstName.addKeyListener (new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter()
{  
  public void keyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) 
          {  
            super.keyReleased(evt);
            if (tfFirst.getText().length() > 0 && tfLast.getText().length() > 0) 
            {  
                bAdd.setEnabled(true);  
            } else 
            {  
                bAdd.setEnabled(false);  
            }  
        }  
});
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add the same listener to both input fields:

```
KeyAdapter adapter = KeyAdapter()
{  
  public void keyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) 
          {  
            super.keyReleased(evt);
            if (tfFirst.getText().trim.length() > 0 && tfLast.getText().trim.length() > 0) 
            {  
                bAdd.setEnabled(true);  
            } else 
            {  
                bAdd.setEnabled(false);  
            }  
        }  
};
tfLastName.addKeyListener(adapter);
tfFirstName.addKeyListener(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

There may be a trailing space in your last name, which you may not be realizing. So better use `trim` before checking the length. Assuming that both `tfFirst` and `tfLast` name are not null, you can try this:

```
if ((tfFirst.getText().trim()).length() > 0 && (tfLast.getText().trim()).length() > 0)
```